# Angular 5 filter pipe

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular5, angular-filters, angular-pipe

I have question about filter pipe angular 5.
Filter pipe works fine, but i have task to filter Date format.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filter"
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.data.DatumRodjenja.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

This is my date format: 01.01.1992. how to ignore dots (.) and search only typing numbers. My code works but i need to type dots when i search for something.

Comment: Just FYI, Angular recommend not using pipes for filters, as it will make the code very inefficient https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe

Comment: Well, remove the dots from it.data.DatumRodjenja.toLowerCase() before testing if the result includes the search text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `replace` and `/\./g` regexp, which fill find all dots and replace it with `''`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filter"
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.data.DatumRodjenja.toLowerCase().replace(/\./g,' ').includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I will in 2 min :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do this way:

```
return it.data.DatumRodjenja.toLowerCase().split('.').join('').includes(searchText);
```